# Outlook 2007 - Switching Stationery Themes easily

Tags: email, templates, microsoft-outlook-2007

Hi I've created a Email Template for Outlook. And have set it up so now when I open a new email my template is display nicely.

But I may not always want to use this template and might have 2 or 3 templates that I need to change between on a regular basis. Is it possible to change to another "Theme" when composing a new email.

There is under the "Options" section of the ribbon a option called "Themes" but this seems more to do with fonts and colours not replacing a proper "Theme" which contains background colours and Image banners in it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wow, I hadn't realized they kept "email templates" after Office 97...

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible without using a macro. I've put a question on stackoverflow.com on how to change it using a macro: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259206/how-do-you-change-outlook-stationery-using-a-macro because I don't know how to do that myself.

If you want to create a custom template, then you can do so using an HTML editor to create a html file. Find out where the themes live on your C drive (varies by operating system). Then put the html file there. You will then see the file appear on the themes list.